# where i can get bootstrap 3.0 carousal with 4 images?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Am trying to put one bootstrap carousal (with 4 images at a time scroll)
 into a bootstrap tabs. I have tried many examples but am not getting. Am using bootstrap 3.0. Can anybody please give an idea for this? Am unable to see at least one bootstrap 3.0 carousal anywhere

Comment: Could you post your code? Probably there is just something wrong with your javascript.

Comment: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-carousel.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the standard markup but add four images inside each of your `.item` slide wrappers.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel4img">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel4img" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel4img" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel4img" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/E83E00/fff&amp;text=Image+1">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/00ACE7/fff&amp;text=Image+2">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/e8117f/fff&amp;text=Image+3">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/C7FF0D/fff&amp;text=Image+4">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/FF0000/fff&amp;text=Image+5">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/E8950C/fff&amp;text=Image+6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/782AE8/fff&amp;text=Image+7">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/393CE8/fff&amp;text=Image+8">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/40083D/fff&amp;text=Image+9">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/FF1919/fff&amp;text=Image+10">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/00E790/fff&amp;text=Image+11">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350/FFB500/fff&amp;text=Image+12">
        </div>
    </div><!--/.carousel-inner -->
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel4img" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel4img" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a> 
</div><!--/.carousel -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.item img {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. is it possible to have caption under the image like 2 to 3 lines